# Compare two dates in shell script

Tags: shell, date, variables

I need to compare two dates which are stored in two variables, the format is `YYYY-MM-DD` . I suppose I can store them in another variables and use some `tr -d "-"`,then compare like integers, but I don’t know how. Thanks in advance !

Comment: why not string operation ?

Comment: I tried [ var1 > var2 ] but it turns true every time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may need to call out to `expr`, depending on your mystery shell:

```
d1="2015-03-31" d2="2015-04-01"
if [ "$d1" = "$d2" ]; then
    echo "same day"
elif expr "$d1" "<" "$d2" >/dev/null; then
    echo "d1 is earlier than d2"
else
    echo "d1 is later than d2"
fi
```

```
d1 is earlier than d2
```

---

The `test` command (or it's alias `[`) only implements string equality and inequality operators. When you give the (non-bash) shell this command:

```
[ "$d1" > "$d2" ]
```

the `> "$d2"` part is treated as stdout redirection. A zero-length file named (in this case) "2015-04-01" is created, and the conditional command becomes

```
[ "$d1" ]
```

and as the variable is non-empty, that evaluates to a success status.

The file is zero size because the `[` command generates no standard output.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `date +%s -d your_date` to get the number of seconds since a fixed instance (1970-01-01, 00:00 UTC) called "epoch". Once you get that it's really easy to do almost anything with dates. And there are a couple of options to convert a number back to date too.