# How can two dates be compared in a shell?

Tags: shell, if-statement, command-line-interface, unix-timestamp

Here is an example of how I would like to use this, though it does not work as-is. i would like to use this specific timestamp only.

```
todate=2017-03-08T19:41:26Z
cond=2017-01-19T19:35:07.000Z
daysdiff=$($todate - $cond)
if [ $daysdiff -gt 5 ];
then
    break
fi
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/quickly-calculate-date-differences

Comment: Lots of details. Do you have GNU date? Which shell? (Do you have bash extensions?)

Comment: ...one of the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310990/compare-two-dates-in-shell-script is entirely applicable, *if* you have GNU date.